# How do I extract x86 related files from kernel source code?

Tags: emacs, x86, kernel, cscope

I am trying to create a cscope index for x86 kernel source files only.

I need to know what files may be needed to work with just x86 source code.

How can I do this?

Comment: the x86 directories in the source trees contain x86 specific codes. or do you want something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `cscope.files`, which will include only files from subfolders:

```
 arch/x86/
```

There was also asm-x86 or asm-i386 in include directory; but in 3.0 kernel these files are moved to arch/x86 too

This will be for only x86-arch-specific code and will not include generic (multiarch) code.

If you want to get cscope for all generic files AND for x86-specific, include into your cscope.files file:

```
every top folder, but not arch (block, crypto, drivers, firmware, fs, include, 
  init, ipc,kernel,lib,mm,net,sound,tools,usr,virt)
and arch/x86 folder
```

Answer (score 1):

The linux kernel has a make target to index the code for cscope.

```
make cscope
```

should do the trick. To filter for a specific architecture, set the 'ARCH' environement variable first:

```
ARCH=x86 make cscope
```

The command will include all the x86 asm directories and leave out the rest. I did not specifically test for x86, but I use it all the time with 'arm'.